# No such file or directory for xml files

Tags: python, xml, for-loop, yolo, annotate

I have annotated images and kept inside annotation folder. I need to convert it to yolov5 format.

```
annotations = [os.path.join('annotations', x) for x in os.listdir('/content/gdrive/My 
Drive/annotations') if x[-3:] == "xml"]
```

now the annotations has:

```
annotations/100_1_0_20170110183726390.xml
annotations/100_1_2_20170105174847679.xml
annotations/100_1_2_20170110182836729.xml
```

when I try to :

```
for ann in tqdm(annotations):
    info_dict = extract_info_from_xml(ann)
    convert_to_yolov5(info_dict)
annotations = [os.path.join('annotations', x) for x in os.listdir('annotations') if x[-3:] == "txt"]
```

I am getting:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'annotations/100_1_0_20170110183726390.xml'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access a folder, `annotations/100_1_0_20170110183726390.xml`, that does not exist (although I think I know what you are trying to do).

The program needs to know the entire path to the file, as in `/content/gdrive/My Drive/annotations/` instead of
`annotations`.

I think `os.path.join('/content/gdrive/My Drive/annotations', x) for x in os.listdir('/content/gdrive/My Drive/annotations') if x[-3:] == "txt"` may work, although a bit wordy.

If you are writing the program in the same directory as `annotations`, you can probably use `os.getcwd()` which will return the current working directory. Then you can use:

`myPath = os.getcwd()`
`myPath = myPath + "annotations/"`
`os.path.join(myPath, x) for x in os.listdir(myPath) if x[-3:] == "txt"`

I think.

Comment: In the first line I have annotations which contains all the xml files. I have listed 3 files as well which is in annotations. then why it is not finding the xml file

Comment: @Nithya It will look for `annotations/100_1_0_20170110183726390.xml` instead of `/content/gdrive/My Drive/annotations/100_1_0_20170110183726390.xml` which is the real location. The first one does not exist.